# Subsonic SimpleRepository Nullable string problem

Tags: string, subsonic, nullable, simplerepository

I am having a problem with subsonic simplerepository. 
I have a users class and it has some optional fields.these optional fields are of type string. As soon 
as I try to persist my object , if the optional fields are null , an exception is being thrown

I know string is already of type nullable so i cannot do something like nullable and string?
so what should i do in this case ?

Another option that I have at this point of time is , before persisting the object, check if the optional attributes are null
if they are null, assign them some dummy data. for example "abracadabra". now whenever i am populating the objects
back from the database i check if optional attributes have this value. 
if they have this value I make the optional attributes empty in my class.

ah! one more thing, please !
can i use ActiveRecord for winforms?

Comment: Thanks .. 

I got the active reocrd to work for me - winforms :) . 
Lots of coffee on a lazy friday afternoon , during the holiday season did the trick for me .

Answer (score 1):

Add the [SubSonicNullString] attribute.

Comment: Even after adding the attribute, I was getting "Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: Abort due to constraint violation
___ may not be NULL". It seems SubSonic is unable to migrate a string to a nullable string, everything worked perfect when I just deleted the database file and let it make a new one. Just a tip for anyone else who ends up here